# Large data through Cron using ZendFramework and Mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, cron

I am using Zend Framework in my web application. I have a requirement to setup a cronjob to execute a php script to retrieve a large amount of data. The number of records is around 3600 which can gradually increase. With this large amount of data I am facing script execution timeout error.

Increasing the script execution time out is not a solution as its not possible to increase the timeout everytime.

Can anyone help me in implementing this in correct way?

Comment: 3600 sounds like a small amount of data in general. Is your data retrieval very complicated? If the data processing is independent of other data, you could limit your cronjob to just 1000 rows and start it more frequently (of course you need a marker for the processed rows). Or do you aggregate information over those rows? Then it might be sped up very much if you can do the aggregation in SQL instead of php.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

in your PHP code, this should allow you to execute for unlimited time, be sure you have the safe mode disabled.

Comment: Will this affect the execution of the script in any other way? Like will it end normally when the execution is over. Will it cause any memory issues?

Comment: Yes it will end properly... now memory issues maybe possible if you dont handle your data properly. A good example is when you try to have a very large recordset in an array, the solution is to to iterate record by record and store that data, or also by shunks of data (records.)